# GSuite emails with Cloud DNS for google domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

I have a domain purchased from Google Domains. For my application to route to compute engine and using my domain, I changed the name servers to the Cloud DNS nameservers as suggested by the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers#find_the_ip_addresses_of_your_name_servers). However, this caused my GMail to stop working for that domain. 
I added NX records as suggested [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9222085?hl=en), but emails are still not being sent to the GMail for the domain.

Here's a image to my DNS record for the full domain:
[image: Image for DNS MX record for domain]

This image is DNS record for a subdomain. 
[image]

Comment: 1) You have conflicting MX records. If you already had MX records for G Suite configured copy them from the old DNS server. 2) Show your registrar DNS NS settings for your domain in your question. 3) It takes time for NS records to propagate. It is best to first fully set up the new DNS server with resource records and then update the NS records at the registrar. Thay way the old and new records will work while the updates propagate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some issues with DNS configuration. I've checked NS records for your domain `bazilla.io` and found something that could be the cause of your issue - there are no NS records accordingly to `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1`:

```
$ dig NS bazilla.io @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS bazilla.io @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 63073
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bazilla.io.                    IN      NS

;; Query time: 132 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:37:44 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39

$ dig NS bazilla.io @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS bazilla.io @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 41198
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bazilla.io.                    IN      NS

;; Query time: 689 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:37:51 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

meanwhile no issues if you ask `ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com` or `ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com`:

```
$ dig NS bazilla.io @ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS bazilla.io @ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18061
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bazilla.io.                    IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.32.107#53(216.239.32.107)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:39:19 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 160

$ dig NS bazilla.io @ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS bazilla.io @ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47841
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bazilla.io.                    IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
bazilla.io.             21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.34.107#53(216.239.34.107)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:40:13 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 160
```

**To solve this issue** you should go to Google Domains and set DNS servers for your domain by following documentation [Manage domain name servers](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) to:

```
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com
```

and wait 24-48 hours for DNS propagation. You can check status of DNS propagation with online tools like [dnsmap.io](https://dnsmap.io/), [dnschecker.org](https://dnschecker.org) or other.

Accordingly to the documentation [GCP Cloud DNS: Set up G Suite MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9222085?hl=en) you should configure 5 MX records:

```
MX server address       Priority

ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM      1
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
```

but it's better to copy them from old DNS server.

You should remove extra records and/or duplicated from DNS zones.

In addition, there's no issue with your subdomain:

```
$ dig NS handson.bazilla.io @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS handson.bazilla.io @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52384
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;handson.bazilla.io.            IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
handson.bazilla.io.     21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
handson.bazilla.io.     21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
handson.bazilla.io.     21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
handson.bazilla.io.     21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:55:58 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 168

$ dig NS handson.bazilla.io @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> NS handson.bazilla.io @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37929
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;handson.bazilla.io.            IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
handson.bazilla.io.     21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
handson.bazilla.io.     21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
handson.bazilla.io.     21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
handson.bazilla.io.     21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.

;; Query time: 73 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:56:03 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 186

$ dig A handson.bazilla.io 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> A handson.bazilla.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41352
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;handson.bazilla.io.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
handson.bazilla.io.     299     IN      A       34.107.144.39

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 18:58:45 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

but still you should remove unnecessary MX records.

Comment: I followed your instructions, and fixed the nameservers, (apparently my nameservers in my Google Domains where ns-cloud-c* but for my main domain in Cloud DNS it was ns-cloud-b*). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: most of the instructions are vague and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please post your question with all the details and I'll have a look on your issue.